# "The method Double(String) is undefined" (How to cast to Double?)

Tags: java, class, casting

I'm using the Stanford version of Eclipse as I'm learning from one of their videos, and using their blank project template.

Basically, I'm writing a custom class "Fraction". One of the constructors takes two numbers (doubles) and converts them to ints before storing them as numerator and denominator.

I've done

```
import java.lang.*;

public class Fraction {
```

And somewhere down I have

```
double numerator = Double(fractionComponents[0]); // fractionComponents is an array of string
double denominator = Double(fractionComponents[1]);
```

but I get the error:

> The method Double(String) is undefined for the type Fraction.

I've also tried extending the class from Double.

Comment: `(type)expr` <-- this is the syntax for a cast. `type(expr)` <-- this is taken as a method call. It wouldn't work anyway, but the above is why you get the syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the static `parseDouble` method, like so:

```
double numerator = Double.parseDouble(fractionComponents[0]);
double denominator = Double.parseDouble(fractionComponents[1]);
```

Note that you could also instantiate a `Double`, but you should prefer to use the static method as it leaves the possibility for the implemention to cache `Double` objects, and it's more clear to the reader what is going on - you're parsing a string for a double value.

If you were to use the constructor, it's not immediately clear what the type of `fractionComponents[0]` is because there's both a `Double(String)` and `Double(double)` constructor.

Comment: Alright thank you very much! Silly me... forgetting the simple things.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot `new`:

```
double numerator = new Double(fractionComponents[0]);
double denominator = new Double(fractionComponents[1]);
```

If you're just interested in the primitive `double` and not its object wrapper `Double` then it's more common to write:

```
double numerator = Double.parseDouble(fractionComponents[0]); 
double denominator = Double.parseDouble(fractionComponents[1]);
```

Comment: @Shakedown The parseX() methods like parseDouble() return primitives.  But valueOf() would return a Double object, which would automatically be unboxed when assigned to a double primitive variable.

Answer (score 1):

It probably should be

```
double numerator = new Double(fractionComponents[0]);
```

etc..

You're missing 'new'

Even then it's better to just do:

```
double numerator =  Double.parseDouble(fractionComponents[0]);
```

to avoid unnecesarry unboxing.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the simple way to solve the problem

```
public class Fraction {
    double numerator = Double.parseDouble(fractionComponents[0]);
    double denominator = Double.parseDouble(fractionComponents[1]);
}
```